# Where's the negative section of a deformation of a Hirzebruch surface?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, curves-and-surfaces

As in [Deformations of Hirzebruch surfaces and toric action](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/69339/deformations-of-hirzebruch-surfaces-and-toric-action),
the Hirzebruch surface $F_n$ can be deformed into $F_{n-2m}$ ($0<2m\leq n$) under the fibration given by
$$
M=\{([x_0:x_1],[y_0:y_1:y_2],t)\in \mathbb{P}^1\times \mathbb{P}^2 \times \mathbb{C} \mid x^n_0y_1−x^n_1y_0+tx^{n−m}_0x^m_1y_2=0\}
$$
over $\mathbb{C}$. What I would like to know is the explicit equations that give the negative section of each Hirzebruch surface in this situation. Of course that of the central fiber $M_0$, which is a ($-n$)-section, is given by $y_0=y_1=0$ in $M_0$. On the other hand, for a noncentral fiber $M_t$ I cannot find the way to determine the equations of its ($-n+2m$)-section.

I would be grateful for any comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can take $y_0 = 0$, $y_1 = -tx_1^m$, $y_2 = x_0^m$.

EDIT. Here is a simple computation of the normal bundle of the curve
$$
C_t = \{([x_0:x_1],[0:-tx_1^m:x_0^m])\} \subset \mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^2
$$
in the surface
$$
S_t = \{x_0^ny_1−x_1^ny_0+tx_0^{n−m}x_1^my_2=0\}
$$
for $t \ne 0$. First, the normal bundle fits into the exact sequence
$$
0 \to N_{C_t/S_t} \to N_{C_t/\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^2} \to N_{S_t/\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^2}\vert_{C_t} \to 0.
$$
Since $C_t$ is a graph of a map $\mathbb{P}^1 \to \mathbb{P}^2$ (of degree $m$), its normal bundle is the pullback of the tangent bundle of $\mathbb{P}^2$, hence its degree is
$$
\deg(N_{C_t/\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^2}) = 3m.
$$
On the other hand, $S_t$ is a divisor of type $(n,1)$ on $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^2$, hence its normal bundle restricted to $C_t$ has the degree
equation which has degree
$$
\deg(N_{S_t/\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^2}\vert_{C_t}) = n + m.
$$
Therefore,
$$
\deg(N_{C_t/S_t}) = 3m - (n + m) = 2m - n.
$$

Comment: Dear Sasha, how to see that this rational curve has self-intersection $(-n+2m)$?

Comment: In other words, how to find its normal bundle, right?  I added a computation to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for showing the details of computations! This is very helpful. So, is it in general true that the normal bundle $N_{\Gamma(f)|(X\times Y)}$ of the graph $\Gamma(f)$ of a morphism $f:X\to Y$ is isomorphic to the pullback tangent bundle $f^*T_Y$ (after identifying $X$ with the graph $\Gamma(f)$)?

Comment: Yes, this is quite general.

Comment: Sorry for late response but thank you for your clear answer and additional information, Sasha. Also thanks, AG learner, for helpful questions!